# How to get vim to run a shell command without freezing the screen

Tags: vim

I recently switched to using VIM (Mac Vim in particular) and I was wondering if it is possible to run the various commands which invoke the shell (:! X) in such a way that they do not freeze VIM and prevent you from working whilst the (sometimes slow) task is run. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Usually, I just have a terminal open and Cmd-Tab over to it.

Comment: That's what I do too, but it costs four keystrokes each time you do it so I'd like a more efficient solution. Perfectionist here!

Comment: Use Ctrl+PageUp and Ctrl+PageDown for switching between tabs.

Comment: 4 keystrokes? I just Cmd-Tab over to it. Or you could use something like DTerm (http://decimus.net/DTerm/)

Comment: Cmd (1) Tab (2) [back] Cmd (3) Tab(4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you execute the task with an ampersand at the end '&' the task will execute in the background and you will get the prompt immediately.

For example:

```
:! find /home -name "*.jpg" > /tmp/results.txt &
```

Will leave the search results in /tmp/results.txt but you will get the control immediately.

Hope it helps.

Regards!

Comment: Thanks but this is not exactly what I'm looking for since this introduces extra steps for viewing the output. Is there any way to keep the output terminal running within VIM (whilst you can switch buffer and keep working)?

Comment: Nop, no way to do it. But you can open a new terminal (in another window or tab) and switch to execute commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this witha combination of `exec`, `silent` and `redraw` like so:

```
:exec 'silent :!find /home -name "*.jpg" > /tmp/results.txt' | :exec 'redraw!'
```